# search if variable exists in any table field and get the table field name

Tags: php, mysql

Using DOM on a webpage, I create a variable like this:

```
$adres = "Bruinbergstraat 2,Bruinberg,8730 Oedelem";
```

In a MySql table I have a lot of records; each record has at least 1 address field, other records have more address fields (max. 7).

When I use this code to find if the variable exists in any of the address fields:

```
$command = "Select * from alleclubs where (adres1 like '%" . $adres ."%' or adres2 LIKE '%" . $adres ."%' or adres3 LIKE '%" . $adres ."%' or adres4 LIKE '%" . $adres ."%' or adres5 LIKE '%" . $adres ."%' or adres6 LIKE '%" . $adres ."%' or adres7 LIKE '%" . $adres ."%')";
```

the result is 0 records found.

How can I solve this so I can get the table field name of the column the variable is in?

Comment: `the result is 0 records found.` so can you confirm whether such text really exists in the table?

Comment: get the record and find the field by php

Comment: The table field "adres1" contains: "Cmp: HO Oedelem,Bruinbergstraat 2,Bruinberg,8730 Oedelem"

Comment: @LucTermote Weird. Run this query directly in phpMyAdmin and see if it gives you correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the table field name of the column the variable is matched with, you can do something like below-

```
"select *
       from (select 
                concat_ws(',',
                    if( adres1 LIKE '%$adres%','adres1',NULL),
                    if( adres2 LIKE '%$adres%','adres2',NULL),
                    if( adres3 LIKE '%$adres%','adres3',NULL),
                    if( adres4 LIKE '%$adres%','adres4',NULL),
                    if( adres5 LIKE '%$adres%','adres5',NULL),
                    if( adres6 LIKE '%$adres%','adres6',NULL),
                    if( adres7 LIKE '%$adres%','adres7',NULL)
                ) as 'matched_column_names',stamnummer
            from alleclubs ) derived_table
where matched_column_names != '' "
```

Then, when iterating each row through PHP, you can just use `explode()` over `,` to get each column name.

**Note:** You can also use `CASE` in MySQL but `CASE` stops when there is a match. The above query will give you all column names that matched with `$adres` for `each single row`.

**UPDATE**:

You can directly check this in your phpMyAdmin with your sample `Bruinbergstraat 2,Bruinberg,8730 Oedelem` as below-

```
select *
       from (select 
                concat_ws(',',
                    if( adres1 LIKE '%Bruinbergstraat 2,Bruinberg,8730 Oedelem%','adres1',NULL),
                    if( adres2 LIKE '%Bruinbergstraat 2,Bruinberg,8730 Oedelem%','adres2',NULL),
                    if( adres3 LIKE '%Bruinbergstraat 2,Bruinberg,8730 Oedelem%','adres3',NULL),
                    if( adres4 LIKE '%Bruinbergstraat 2,Bruinberg,8730 Oedelem%','adres4',NULL),
                    if( adres5 LIKE '%Bruinbergstraat 2,Bruinberg,8730 Oedelem%','adres5',NULL),
                    if( adres6 LIKE '%Bruinbergstraat 2,Bruinberg,8730 Oedelem%','adres6',NULL),
                    if( adres7 LIKE '%Bruinbergstraat 2,Bruinberg,8730 Oedelem%','adres7',NULL)
                ) as 'matched_column_names',stamnummer
            from alleclubs ) derived_table
where matched_column_names != '';
```

Comment: Sorry vivek_23, in phpMyadim I tried this and get this error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '$adres = 'Bruinbergstraat 2,Bruinberg,8730 Oedelem' select conc' at line 1

Comment: @LucTermote so what did you get? Also, if you are trying in phpmyadmin , make sure you replace `$adres` with your string

Comment: @LucTermote Directly use the string. Don't do `$adres = `

Comment: Replacing $adres in the select statement by "BRUINBERGSTRAAT 2,BRUINBERG,8730 OEDELEM" I get error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') as 'matched_column_names' from alleclubs LIMIT 0, 30' at line 10

Comment: Then I get a table with only the header: "matched_column_names" with empty rows?

Comment: @LucTermote weird. Works fine on my machine. Can you export your table, edit your post and add a link to your exported SQL file? I will have a look

Comment: @LucTermote You can use [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com) to show the SQL file.

Comment: Yes you did it! Thanks very much, now I know in which field the address is, I can find the corresponding GPS coordinates in the fields gps1,gps2, gps3,... to use to show a Google maps. The address is not always accurate enough e.g. when the street is given without a number.

Comment: @LucTermote Could you please use this comment section to  notify me about any issue you face?

Comment: @LucTermote `I changed my code with the above "select....", but I have already 2 addresses where the result is empty for matched_column_names. I wonder if the problem can have something to do with upper- and lowercase?`. 

Probably. So, you could fix that by 2 steps. 

$adres = strtolower($adres);

AND 

change the columns to lower case before matching.

Like, for example, `if( adres1 LIKE` in query for all columns to `if( lower(adres1) LIKE`

Comment: I used UPDATE alleclubs SET adres1 = UPPER(adres1) to change the 7 adres-fields; but that seems not to solve the problem.

Comment: @LucTermote I suggest better not do that. Better do `$adres = strtolower($adres);` in your PHP code and make these changes in your query. `if( adres1 LIKE` to `if( lower(adres1) LIKE`
`if( adres2 LIKE` to `if( lower(adres2) LIKE`
`if( adres3 LIKE` to `if( lower(adres3) LIKE`
`if( adres4 LIKE` to `if( lower(adres4) LIKE`
`if( adres5 LIKE` to `if( lower(adres5) LIKE`
`if( adres6 LIKE` to `if( lower(adres6) LIKE`
`if( adres7 LIKE` to `if( lower(adres7) LIKE`

Comment: Not at all, a lot of addresses give an empty result of the select query. Must the format concerning spaces and comma and " be exactly the same in $adres as in the field adres1...adres7? If so, I have to change all the addresses in the database.

Comment: @LucTermote Hmm... like I said, you can eliminate the issue with lowercase and uppercase, but with spaces,punctuation marks etc, it needs to be exact.